# Kotlin SpringBoot and JPA - Problem with relation OneToMany-ManyToOne

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I am trying to create a relation OneToMany between two entities and always get an error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory':

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-11-23 12:17:20.082 ERROR 17130 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [com.moises.kotlinstoreapi.model.Customer.purchases, com.moises.kotlinstoreapi.model.Purchase.purchasesLines]
...
```

I have created the same type of relation with other two entities (Customer with Purchase) but in this case it doesn't run...

Product code:
    package com.moises.kotlinstoreapi.model

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import javax.persistence.*
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

@Entity
@Table(name="products")
data class Product (
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0,
    @NotBlank
    val title: String = "",
    @NotEmpty
    val price: Double = 999.99,
    @NotNull
    val created_at: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
    val update_at: LocalDateTime? = null,

    /**
    * Relations
    *
    */
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="product")
    val purchaseLine: PurchaseLine? = null
)
```

Purchase code:

```
package com.moises.kotlinstoreapi.model

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference
import com.sun.istack.NotNull
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import javax.persistence.*
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty

@Entity
@Table(name="purchases")
data class Purchase(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private val id: Long=0,
    @Column(name="notes", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    val notes: String = "",
    @NotNull
    val created_at: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
    val update_at: LocalDateTime? = null,

    /**
    * Relations
    *
    */
    //@ManyToOne(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL),fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    //@JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
    //@JsonBackReference
    //val customer: Customer? = null,

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="purchase", cascade=arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL), fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    var purchasesLines: List<PurchaseLine> = emptyList()
)
```

PurchaseLine code:

```
package com.moises.kotlinstoreapi.model

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference
import javax.persistence.*
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty

@Entity
@Table(name="purchase_lines")
data class PurchaseLine(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private val id: Long=0,
    @NotEmpty
    val quantity: Int = 1,

    /**
    * Relations
    *
    */
    @OneToOne(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL))
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    val product: Product? = null,

    @ManyToOne(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL),fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="purchase_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    var purchase: Purchase? = null
)
```

I am usin IntelliJ with Maven and OpenJDK 11 in Ubuntu.

My pow.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.moises</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-store-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kotlin-store-api</name>
    <description>API store with Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.50</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: My guess is that he error is caused by the fact that the two OneToMany associations listed in the error message are eager (why?) and use List instead of Set. Keep your toMany associations lazy: that will avoid ruining the performances of your app. It will also avoid that problem.

Comment: I don't have idea what i do. It's my first Kotlin/Java, Spring & JPA project.
It ran OK when I cleaned `fetch= FetchType.EAGER` from relations in 'Purchase'. It mantein the List, but I want check with Set, use it has more sense.